# How to refresh a stream of data with an OpenGL texture?

Tags: java, opengl-es

I have to deal with a continuous stream of data that fills double arrays, each of which corresponds to images that I display on the main screen. Rather than creating bitmaps, I want to use `OpenGL` to refresh the display with the incoming data.

So, I put this in a `loadTexture` method:

```
int[] textureId = new int[1];
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size*size*3);
        buffer.put(data); #  where data is some byte[size*size*3]; 
        buffer.position(0);
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureId, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId[0] );
        GLES20.glTexSubImage2D ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, 512, 512, 0,
        GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer );
```

But the images are not refreshed, so that I added the same piece of code in the `onDrawFrame` method of my `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`, but it do not work either. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there was an error in the method call that I took for a tutorial example ;) When running :

```
GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512,
                GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bufer);
```

it ran fine